# Custom CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a CreateUserWizard control and I want to customize it to meet my requirements.

My question is: it possible using the CreateUserWizard control to move the Email textbox to another step then the **CreateUserWizardStep** step?

What I want to achieve is from the step #1 to have the UserName, Password and ConfirmPassword and on Step #2 the Email, a custom ConfirmEmail, SecurityQuestion/SecurityAnswer and other information.

I know how to add a wizard step but if I move any of the default textbox I'm getting an error about missing field in the CreateUserWizard step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question I start to try some alternative I havent think about. Like adding a WizardStep on top of the CreateUserWizard step where I have UserNameTextBox, PasswordTextBox and ConfirmPasswordTextBox.

The CreateUserWizard step contains a hiden UserName, Password and ConfirmPassword textbox which I set the values on ActiveStepChanged event. that step also contains the other required fields to create the user sich as Question and answer.

This meet my requirements and I am a happy programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test with this structure

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" >
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server">
           .....
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep> 
        <asp:WizardStep runat="server">
            ...
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Control of validating with `ValidationGroup` property, in order to activate validating just when needed

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response Candie. It is actually what I was trying to do. The problem is when CreateUserWizard is fired (the event) the user will be created and all required information are needed at that point.

Comment: I'am happy to help you Mario, you can use ValidationGroup on your button and validators, in order to control postback and validation

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm showing how to customized create user wizard & I'm using `Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 For Web`

In your register.aspx Page

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" CreateUserButtonText="Submit">
                <WizardSteps>
                    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User name:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="form-group">
                                    <td>E-mail:
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>First Name:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Last Name:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                    <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server"></asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                </WizardSteps>
            </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

And `CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser` code behind your Register.aspx.cs file use this code

```
        var manager = new UserManager();
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = CreateUserWizard1.UserName };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, CreateUserWizard1.Password);
        // Get the UserId of the just-added user
        MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);
        Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
        //Get Profile Data Entered by user in Create User Wizard control
        String FirstName = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName")).Text;
        String LastName = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName")).Text;
        // Insert a new record into User_Profile
        // Get your Connection String from the web.config. MembershipConnectionString is the name I have in my web.config
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO yourDBTableName(dbTcolumn,dbTcolumn, dbTcolumn) values(@dbTcolumn, @dbTcolumn)";

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTcolumn", FirstName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTcolumn", LastName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbTcolumn", newUserId);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }
```

Here I'm not `using RequiredFieldValidator`. If you want to use, Just use Register.aspx page this bellow section

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server"
                                            ControlToValidate="FirstName"  ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and add `CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser` code behind `if (result.Succeeded)` in your Register.aspx.cs

I hope this is help to you customized your create user wizard.
 
 Thanks